# Возможно ли настроить работу Asp.Net Core контроллеров как синглетоны?

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, controller, singleton, asp.net-core-2

При запросе с клиента Asp.Net Core каждый раз заново создаёт контроллер и резолвит все его зависимости, а так же зависимости зависимостей и так далее.

По моему мнению это очень дорогостоящая операция, ну может быть не очень но всё же это лишние действия.

И у меня вопрос, можно ли как-то сделать что бы контроллеры были синглетонами.

Я понимаю почему сейчас они Scoped, по причине потокобезопасности.
Но и с другой стороны, достаточно просто не делать никакого state у контроллеров, и это тоже обеспечит потокобезопасность.

Возможно контроллеры вообще в Asp.Net Core никак не сделать синглетонами простым способом, по точу что там вся инфраструктура завязана на том какие они сейчас есть. Но возможно есть какие-то подходы или решения этой ситуации?

Может быть есть какие-то кастомные сторонние решения (MVC) для этого на .Net Core?

В этом вопросе я рассчитываю даже не столько на правильный ответ решающий всю эту ситуацию, но на обсуждение о возможности и нужности такого.

Пока сам изучал этот вопрос узнал что есть такие штуки как

1. IControllerActivator - как я понял отвечает как раз за получение
   (создание) контроллера. И по идее в нём можно не создавать новые
   контроллеры каждый раз а вытягивать из DI контейнера синглетон
   объект.
2. IControllerFactory

В случае использования `IControllerActivator` пока не очень понятно получится или нет, так как такие понятия как Request, Response как есть в Asp.Nеt Core жёстко прописаны внутрь контроллера как его свойства.

Comment: С какой целью Вы хотите сделать это? Как правило создание контроллера не так дорого, как обработка бизнес логики приложения или например доступ к слою данных... может сперва начать оптимизацию там, если есть проблемы с производительностью, конечно)
Прошу заметить, что все зависимости Scoped создаются один раз на запрос, а не на каждый резолв зависимости

Comment: @SultanovShamil в данном вопросе чисто теоретический интерес. С другой стороны мне просто не нравится как они создаются сейчас, я не думаю что буду это в свои проектах переделывать если простого способа нет. А так же вообще хочется узнать мнение других людей на эту тему.